# How to make dynamic elastic search query based on my given input values in Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have written elastic search query in static values, now i want to make  as a dynamic like i have input fields, based on the input values i have to make my dynamic elastic search query. how can i do it? any one please update my answer.

> INPUT

```
{
"userID" : "USER1", 
"groupID" : "5b278f8856db693c457b4697", 
"contentType " : "question", 
"contentID" : "5", 
"contentFlow": [
            {
                "contentId": "123",
                "contentType": "topic"
            },
            {
                "contentId": "456",
                "contentType": "concept"
            },
            {
                "contentId": "100",
                "contentType": "sdl"
            }
        ]
      }
```

> STATIC QUERY

```
{
   "size":999,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "userId":"USER1"
               }
            },
            {
               "term":{
                  "contentId":"5"
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must":[
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "contentPath.contentType":"topic"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "contentPath.contentId":"123"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must":[
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "contentPath.contentType":"concept"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "contentPath.contentId":"456"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must":[
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "contentPath.contentType":"sdl"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "contentPath.contentId":"100"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I am new to learning elastic search, kindly help me out on this problem

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems that you havn't tried any wrapper to prepare the query for elastcisearch. There are many library that provide objective query builder for Elasticsearch bundle and elasticsearch-php client. You can easily build any Elasticsearch query and transform it to an array.

You can visit the below links:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_community_dsls.html

https://github.com/makinacorpus/php-elastic-query

Hope this will help to solve your problems.